# translate bounding box anotation from [xmin, ymin, width, height] to YOLOv7

Tags: yolo, yolov5

I'm struggling with translating coordinates from [xmin, ymin, width, height] to YOLOv7 representation, could someone help me, please?

For example my image is `width = 9477px`, `hight = 23354px`,
the annotation for `[xmin, ymin, width, height]` is :

```
[2009 21947 207 251]
```

I would like to know how I translate it to YoloV7 coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

got an answer to it:

```
def convert_bbox_coco2yolo(img_width, img_height, bbox):
    """
    Convert bounding box from COCO  format to YOLO format

    Parameters
    ----------
    img_width : int
        width of image
    img_height : int
        height of image
    bbox : list[int]
        bounding box annotation in COCO format: 
        [top left x position, top left y position, width, height]

    Returns
    -------
    list[float]
        bounding box annotation in YOLO format: 
        [x_center_rel, y_center_rel, width_rel, height_rel]
    """
    
    # YOLO bounding box format: [x_center, y_center, width, height]
    # (float values relative to width and height of image)
    x_tl, y_tl, w, h = bbox

    dw = 1.0 / img_width
    dh = 1.0 / img_height

    x_center = x_tl + w / 2.0
    y_center = y_tl + h / 2.0

    x = x_center * dw
    y = y_center * dh
    w = w * dw
    h = h * dh

    return [x, y, w, h]
```